# Cloth Simulator gives strange shading

Tags: cloth-simulation

Whenever I extrude cloth and plays the animation , it mixed up with another side of mesh , How can I overcome from It ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloth simulation works best with a 'flat' mesh - rather than one extruded to give thickness - otherwise both 'sides' of the cloth have to be simulated separately and they can overlap (which is, I believe, what you are seeing). If you want to give your cloth thickness, you can add a Solidify modifier below the Cloth modifier in the modifier stack. In this way the cloth simulation will simulate a 'flat' cloth while the solidifier modifier will give it 'thickness', without the possibility of opposite sides intersecting.